# Cause of DNS A record delays

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

I have some hosts that come up on demand in EC2 and when they do the service that starts them creates an A record in Route53 under an existing zone.

The A records are of the form:  randomid.example.com.
So it's not an update or change of an existing name/IP pair, it's completely new entry.  There shouldn't be any propagation delay.

What I'm seeing is that after the entry has been added and available for lookup with DNS on any of the Amazon servers, my own client PC can't resolve the name for what seems like 5-10 minutes.  You ping it, and I'd expect to see an IP for it.  But I simply get "no such host".

If I change my /etc/resolv.conf nameserver entry from my local nameserver to 8.8.8.8 (google dns), it resolves.  I switch back and it doesn't resolve.  This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Route53 given that google answers.

What would cause this? Shouldn't my local resolver be querying the relevant nameservers and eventually the nameserver for example.com which should get an answer for randomid.example.com?

Comment: What makes you think that new entries don't have propogation delay?

Comment: @Peterdk - It's a brand new entry.  You're not propagating a new IP address to an existing A record out to the world where it may be cached.  Therefore a resolver would do a full lookup, first to .com then to .example.com to obtain the IP back to the client.  But I'm unsure why it's not being resolved by my local dns nameserver and the nameserver of my ISP.

Comment: hmm, perhaps it's related to anycast.  Route53 uses that.  So it's a different type of propagation delay.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> There shouldn't be any propagation delay.

Yes, there should be.

All DNS configuration has a "propagation delay."¹

In the case of new records, a lookup of a hostname before the record is actually available from the authoritative name servers results in *negative caching:* when a resolver looks up a non-existent record, the `NXDOMAIN` response is cached by the resolver for a period of time, and this response is returned for subsequent request until the default TTL elapses and the response is evicted from the resolver's cache.

> Negative caching is useful as it reduces the response time for negative answers.  It also reduces the number of messages that have to be sent between resolvers and name servers hence overall network traffic.

> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2308

When you use `dig` to query the new record, you'll see the TTL counting down to 0.  Once that happens, you start seeing the expected answer.  On Linux the `watch` utility is handy for this, as in `watch -n 1 'dig example.com'`.

The timer should be set from the minimum TTL, which is found in your hosted zone's `SOA` record:

> **The minimum time to live (TTL).** This value helps define the length of time that an NXDOMAIN result, which indicates that a domain does not exist, should be cached by a DNS resolver. Caching this negative result is referred to as negative caching. The duration of negative caching is the lesser of the SOA record's TTL or the value of the minimum TTL field.  The default minimum TTL on Amazon Route 53 SOA records is 900 seconds.

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/SOA-NSrecords.html

There's the source of your 5-10 minutes.  It's actually a worst case of 15 minutes (900 seconds).

Reducing this timer will reduce the amount of time that well-behaved resolvers will cache the fact that the record does not (yet) exist.

"Great," you object, "but I didn't query the hostname before it existed.  What now?"

You probably did, because Route 53 does not immediately make records visible. There's a brief lag between the time a change is made to a hosted zone and the time Route 53 begins returning the records.

The Route 53 API supports the [`GetChange`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_GetChange.html) action, which should not return `INSYNC` until the authoritative servers for your hosted zone are returning the expected answer for the change (and of course this uses "change" in the sense that both "insert" and "update" are a "change").

You can also determine this by directly querying one of the servers specifically assigned to your hosted zone (as seen in the console, among other places).

```
$ dig @ns-xxxx.awsdns-yy.com example.com
```

Because you are querying an authoritative server directly, you'll see the result of the change as soon as the server has it available, because there is no resolver in the path that will cache responses.

---

¹For the purposes of this answer, I'm glossing over the fact that what is commonly referred to as "propagation delay" in DNS is actually a nothing of the sort -- it's actually a TTL-based cache eviction delay for existing records.

Comment: I think it is important NOT to talk about propagation delay, even if everyone says so. Because it gives the false impression things are done "top-down" and that you just need to wait to get proper results. This is wrong. You get proper (newer) results ONLY if you query AND your cache is either empty or the entry TTL value has expired. Conflating propagation and TTL gives false impression.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek that's a fair point. I'll contemplate some improvement, here.